# aligning numerical data in columns on decimal marker

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I created this table:

[image]

I use this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=2.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm, includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{  {fig/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}



\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{\cdot}{#1}} % and yet another handy shortcut macro
\newcolumntype{,}{D{,}{,}{-2}}

\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cLcccccc@{}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
 & Amostra & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H60} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H60 Modificado} \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
  &  \textbf{Série} & 1  & 2  & 1   & 2 \\
  &  \textbf{Data de Formação} & 10/mar & 22/abr & 08/abr & 10/abr \\
  &  \textbf{Data de Medição} & 27/mar & 28/abr & 11/abr & 11/abr \\
\addlinespace
  \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{Filler Efectivo (\%)} & 18,25 & 18,3  & 17,6  & 17,1 \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem ($g.m^{-2}$)} & 83,8  & 85,0  & 82,8  & 83,0 \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica ($g.cm^{-3}$)} & 0,72  & 0,7   & 0,7   & 0,7 \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão ($cm^3.g^{-1}$)} & 1,40  & 1,4   & 1,5   & 1,5 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley 100ml (s)} & 3,8   & 5,3   & 4,1   & 3,4 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL ($ml.min^{-1}$)} & 192   & 199,8 & 414,1 & 410,2 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento ($kPa.m^2.g^{-1}$)} & 1,76  & 2,1   & 2,3   & 2,3 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção ($N.m.g^{-1}$)} & 34,6  & 37,2  & 42,5  & 43,4 \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\%)} & 2,9   & 2,7   & 2,8   & 2,6 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness ($kN.m^{-1}$)} & 535  & 521,7 & 593,7 & 609,6 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. ($J.g^{-1}$)} & 0,7   & 0,7   & 0,9   & 0,8 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento ($mN.m^2.g^{-1})$} & 5,6   & 5,7   & 5,7   & 5,5 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &   \textbf{C.E.D.L. ($m^2.kg^{-1})$} & 48,5  & 47,6  & 43,4  & 43,7 \\
  &  \textbf{Opacidade (\%)} & 88,1  & 88,1  & 86,2  & 85,9 \\
  &  \textbf{Brancura R457 (\%)} & 84,6  & 84,9  & 84,6  & 85,8 \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

But, I want to center the numbers (in columns) with commas. How I can do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve what you want using either the `dcolumn` or `siunitx` packages, both of which you load. Cleaning up the markup, fixing your units (which should not be italic, so could be done using `\mathrm` but easier using the `siunitx` command `\si`) and adding in alignment using just `siunitx` gives:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR} % No Portuguese locale built-in, but French I think covers it

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \sisetup{table-format = {3,1}}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll*6{S}@{}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
 & Amostra & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H60} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H60 Modificado} \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
  &  \textbf{Série} & {1}  & {2}  &  {1}   & {2} \\
  &  \textbf{Data de Formação} & {10/mar} & {22/abr} & {08/abr} & {10/abr} \\
  &  \textbf{Data de Medição} & {27/mar} & {28/abr} & {11/abr} & {11/abr} \\
\addlinespace
  \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{Filler Efectivo (\%)} & 18,25 & 18,3  & 17,6  & 17,1 \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem (\si{g.m^{-2}})} & 83,8  & 85,0  & 82,8  & 83,0 \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica (\si{g.cm^{-3}})} & 0,72  & 0,7   & 0,7   & 0,7 \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão (\si{cm^3.g^{-1}})} & 1,40  & 1,4   & 1,5   & 1,5 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley \SI{100}{ml} (\si{s})} & 3,8   & 5,3   & 4,1   & 3,4 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL (\si{ml.min^{-1}})} & 192   & 199,8 & 414,1 & 410,2 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento (\si{kPa.m^2.g^{-1}})} & 1,76  & 2,1   & 2,3   & 2,3 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção (\si{N.m.g^{-1}})} & 34,6  & 37,2  & 42,5  & 43,4 \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\%)} & 2,9   & 2,7   & 2,8   & 2,6 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness (\si{kN.m^{-1}})} & 535  & 521,7 & 593,7 & 609,6 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. (\si{J.g^{-1}})} & 0,7   & 0,7   & 0,9   & 0,8 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento (\si{mN.m^2.g^{-1})}} & 5,6   & 5,7   & 5,7   & 5,5 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &   \textbf{C.E.D.L. (\si{m^2.kg^{-1})}} & 48,5  & 47,6  & 43,4  & 43,7 \\
  &  \textbf{Opacidade (\%)} & 88,1  & 88,1  & 86,2  & 85,9 \\
  &  \textbf{Brancura R457 (\%)} & 84,6  & 84,9  & 84,6  & 85,8 \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

or using `dcolumn` would look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR}
\usepackage{dcolumn}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll*6{D{,}{,}{3.1}}@{}}
  \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
 & Amostra & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H60} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{H60 Modificado} \\
   \cmidrule{2-6}
  &  \textbf{Série} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2}  &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{1}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} \\
  &  \textbf{Data de Formação} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10/mar} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{22/abr} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{08/abr} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{10/abr} \\
  &  \textbf{Data de Medição} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{27/mar} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{28/abr} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11/abr} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11/abr} \\
\addlinespace
  \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Estruturais}} & \textbf{Filler Efectivo (\%)} & 18,25 & 18,3  & 17,6  & 17,1 \\
  & \textbf{Gramagem (\si{g.m^{-2}})} & 83,8  & 85,0  & 82,8  & 83,0 \\
  & \textbf{Massa Volúmica (\si{g.cm^{-3}})} & 0,72  & 0,7   & 0,7   & 0,7 \\
  & \textbf{Índice de Mão (\si{cm^3.g^{-1}})} & 1,40  & 1,4   & 1,5   & 1,5 \\
  & \textbf{Resistência ao ar Gurley \SI{100}{ml} (\si{s})} & 3,8   & 5,3   & 4,1   & 3,4 \\
  & \textbf{Rugosidade  ar Bendtsen, FL (\si{ml.min^{-1}})} & 192   & 199,8 & 414,1 & 410,2 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Mecânicas}} & \textbf{Índice de Rebentamento (\si{kPa.m^2.g^{-1}})} & 1,76  & 2,1   & 2,3   & 2,3 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Tracção (\si{N.m.g^{-1}})} & 34,6  & 37,2  & 42,5  & 43,4 \\
  &  \textbf{Extensão (\%)} & 2,9   & 2,7   & 2,8   & 2,6 \\
  &  \textbf{Tensile Stiffness (\si{kN.m^{-1}})} & 535  & 521,7 & 593,7 & 609,6 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice T.E.A. (\si{J.g^{-1}})} & 0,7   & 0,7   & 0,9   & 0,8 \\
  &  \textbf{Índice de Rasgamento (\si{mN.m^2.g^{-1})}} & 5,6   & 5,7   & 5,7   & 5,5 \\
\addlinespace
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=C]{90}{Ópticas}} &   \textbf{C.E.D.L. (\si{m^2.kg^{-1})}} & 48,5  & 47,6  & 43,4  & 43,7 \\
  &  \textbf{Opacidade (\%)} & 88,1  & 88,1  & 86,2  & 85,9 \\
  &  \textbf{Brancura R457 (\%)} & 84,6  & 84,9  & 84,6  & 85,8 \\
    \cmidrule[0.8pt]{2-6}
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Both packages have documentation giving details of how to achieve this: I'm not clear which part of the process specifically caused issues here (perhaps commas rather than decimal points?).

Comment: Just out of interest: Why not use `\si{\g\per\square\m}` instead of `\si{g.m^{-2}}` (and equivalently for the other units)? Also, shouldn't `\%` be `\si{\percent}`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I was sticking to the OP's syntax other than fixing actual errors: `siunitx` is designed to handle 'literal' input, and `%` is a bit of an odd one (it's not a unit but is supported as it's convenient!).